# linking errors between boost::program_options and armadillo for cmake generated eclipse project

Tags: c++, eclipse, boost, environment-variables, armadillo

So I had successfully been using cmake and boost in my project.
I wanted to start incorporating armadillo (4.400.1)

I use enivronment modules (http://modules.sourceforge.net/) on my system. 
I built with gcc-4.8.1.
CentOS 6.4.
I installed OpenBLAS (0.2.10) and armadillo from source and created environment modules.

In the past I only needed to prepend `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` with lib directories, but this was not sufficient for armadillo, as I was getting linking errors (unable to find lib) for the following:

```
g++ example1.cpp -o example1 -O2 -larmadillo
```

Using the `-L` option works:

```
g++ example1.cpp -o example1 -O2 -larmadillo -L${ARMADILLO_HOME}/lib
```

I am already placing the armadillo lib directory in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. How do I set environment variables so the following will link without error?

```
g++ example1.cpp -o example1 -O2 -larmadillo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to place the armadillo lib directory in the environment variable `LIBRARY_PATH` not `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Doing this allowed the linking to proceed without error when issuing the command:

```
g++ example1.cpp -o example1 -O2 -larmadillo
```